# not able to use sp_executesql command

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to execute below query

**SELECT *, IDENTITY( int ) AS IDColumn INTO #SmootheningTable  FROM  @TableName**

where **#SmootheningTable** is temporary table 
and **@TableName** is name of table

I need to use command either *EXEC* or *sp_executesql* to execute.

If I use EXEC, I wont be able to use #SmootheningTable in later portion of my stored procedure.
And while trying sp_executesql, I am getting error stating @statement error.
How can I use sp_executesql for above given query.

Or is there any other way to execute?

this is the query I am using

```
DECLARE @TablePlaceHolder VARCHAR(50)='';
DECLARE @SmootheningQuery NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT *, IDENTITY( int ) AS IDColumn INTO #SmootheningTable  FROM  @TablePlaceHolder';
EXEC sp_executesql @SmootheningQuery, N'@TablePlaceHolder varchar(50)', @PlanDetailTempTableName
```

and i am getting below error

> Must declare the table variable "@TablePlaceHolder".

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably a simple mistake, show the code you used.

Comment: What error you got..?

Comment: I am having issues as table name is in varaiable

Comment: I have included query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:-

**First** : Putting the variable name inside the string, put in out like next:-

instead of this line:-

```
DECLARE @SmootheningQuery NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT *, IDENTITY( int ) AS 
IDColumn INTO #SmootheningTable  FROM  @TablePlaceHolder';
```

Type this line:-

```
DECLARE @SmootheningQuery NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT *, IDENTITY( int ) AS 
IDColumn INTO #SmootheningTable  FROM  ' + @TablePlaceHolder;
```

**Second**: Don't use local temp table within `sp_executeSql`,

The Local temporary table [*with one hash #* ] is visible in current session only, use global temporary tables  instead [*with two hashes ##* ] are visible in all sessions,

So instead of

```
#SmootheningTable
```

Type

```
##SmootheningTable
```

**Demo (All Code): -**

```
Create table MyTable (id int , name nvarchar(100))
go

insert into MyTable values (1, 'Ahmed');
insert into MyTable values (2, 'Abdelqader');
go

declare 
    @TableName varchar(50),
    @MyQuery nvarchar(200)

set  @TableName = 'MyTable'

set @MyQuery = 'select * Into ##MYTempTable From ' + @TableName 

exec sp_executesql @MyQuery



select * from ##MYTempTable
```

**Result:-**

```
id  name
1   Ahmed
2   Abdelqader
```

Comment: I think it's not advisable to use Global Temp Table, They are visible to all connections of SQLServer and only destroyed when the last connection referencing the table is closed (in which we have created the Global Temporary Table).

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This,

```
CREATE PROC  usp_SmootheningTable
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT *, IDENTITY( int ) AS IDColumn   INTO #SmootheningTable FROM 
  TableName
  SELECT * FROM  #SmootheningTable 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
Columns
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TableName = 'TableName'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT  TOP 10 * FROM '+@TableName

INSERT INTO #Temp
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```